# autocomplete="off" display when i edit the primefaces datatable row and display the total value of total rows in input textbox

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
            <p:column headerText="job">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{p.job}" />  
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{p.job}" style="width:100%"/></f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Pkg">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{p.qty}" />  
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{p.qty}" style="width:100%" /></f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>
```

When i display the total value of one cell in datatable with input textbox, autocomplete="off" display and cannot update anymore to the rows in the primefaces.

Can someone please help me? Even if i set autocomplete to "off", I really have no idea for the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I have this for change the page for display:

```
action="/navPages/dir/page.xhtml?faces-redirect=false"
```

I solved it with:

```
action="/navPages/dir/page.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"
```

in a `<p:commandButton ... />`